# Вопрос по классам в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, инициализация

Я недавно стал заниматься программированием на Pyhton и ещё не очень разобрался с классами. У меня есть загруженная картинка pic, и как мне её инициализировать. 
Я пробовал вот так - `pic.__init__(self)` но когда я запускаю программу мне компьютер выводит
`ValueError: size needs to be (int width, int height)` (ошибка именно в этой строке).

Comment: Если объект уже создан, не нужно пытаться вызвать его метод `__init__`. Вообще - добавьте в вопрос код, с которым у вас возникли проблемы.

Comment: Артем, впредь давай своим вопросам заголовки, отражающие суть твоей проблемы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__init__` - это конструктор класса. Когда вы создаёте экземпляр класса - вызывается конструктор. Таким образом, в результате выполнения данного кода

```py
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, some_arg):
        print(f'Вы передали в конструктор: {some_arg}')

some_class_instance = SomeClass(4)
```

в качестве вывода Вы получите

```
Вы передали в конструктор: 4
```

Как Вы можете заметить, конструктор явно не был вызван, в то время, как инструкции, указанные в нём были выполнены.

Судя по тексту ошибки, Вам следует передать в конструктор размеры изображения, его ширину и высоту при создании объекта класса